# Primary key VS Foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Im a newbie here

I created one table with primary key customer_id , and another table with a foreign key customer_id to join it to the first table

my question

when I want to enter data in the two tables , should I insert the customer_id twice ( one in the first table and the other in the second  ) .

should I do that in every time I insert data ?? 
thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `CustomerId` table represents each customer in the `Customer` table. So whenever a new customer arrives, you create an id for that customer.

For other tables that "relate" to the customer, you insert a customer_id for each entry.

E.g.

```
Customer
CustomerId, CustomerName
```

Each customer has a unique id..

```
ProductSold
ProductId, ProductName, CustomerId
```

You can now tell which customer bought a product because of the foreign key in the Product table. 
So for each product, you insert the customer's id that bought it. I hope that makes sense.

-- A new customer, requires a new id (when you insert a new customer)
-- A product bought by customer, requires a foreign CustomerId to identify its buyer.

So 2 `CustomerId` inserts.

So yes.. you are right lol :P

Comment: Yes, the tables are related by that key -- so it must be inserted into Customer.ID, and written as Order.FK_Customer. (ProductSold would probable actually be an Order or OrderLine, in a real system.)